# Laravel Model request with several joins

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

While I am able to make simple requests with Model, I can't say the same for more complicated ones.
I know I don't necessarily have to use Model and can use DB facade but still, I want to know how it's supposed to be done.

Here's a request I made using DB :

```
DB::table('relationships')
        ->Join('users','users.id','=','relationships.user_id')
        ->Join('roles','roles.id','=','relationships.role_id')
        ->Join('bundles','bundles.id','=','relationships.related_id')
        ->Join('pools','bundles.id','=','pools.bundle_id')
        ->whereIn('pools.name',$pools)
        ->whereIn('roles.name',$roles)
        ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name','users.mail_address','roles.name AS role_name','bundles.name AS bundle_name', 'pools.name AS pool_name')
        ->get();
```

On a first attempt, I tried this:

```
User::whereHas('relationships', function($req) use($roles) {
            $req->whereHas('bundle', function($req){
                $req->whereIn('name', $pools);
            });
            $req->whereHas('role', function ($req){
                $req->whereIn('name', $roles);
            });
        })
        ->with('relationships', 'relationships.role:id,name', 'relationships.bundle:id,name')
        ->get();
        }
```

Problem is, using "with" just select everything unconditionally, ignoring previous tests you made earlier (whereHas, whereIn).
So I'd have to again filter on each table in the with statement.

Then I ended up doing this:

```
$pools = request()->input('pools.*.name');
        return $prepReq = User::whereHas('relationships', function($req) use($pools, $roles) {
            $req->whereHas('bundle', function($req) use ($pools){
                $req->whereHas('pools', function($req) use ($pools){
                    $req->whereIn('name', $pools);
                });
            });
            $req->whereHas('role', function ($req){
                $req->whereIn('name', $roles);
            });
        })
        ->with(['relationships' => function ($query) use($pools, $roles){
            $query->whereHas('role', function ($query){
                $query->whereIn('name', $roles)
                ->select('id','name');
            })->select('id','name');
            
        }])
        ->get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'mail_address']);
```

Then I got lost into this and gave up.
Another thing that made me sweat is that when you go nested using "with", you can select columns only on the last table.

For example: "relations.bundle.pools" => I can select columns on pools but not on relationships or bundles, does that mean i have to imbricate with statements for each table ?

As you can see, I am a bit clueless on how things are supposed to be done

I would like any advice or help regarding this matter

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

When using Laravel, you should be setting up the [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) for each model

Based on your select statement from above, and assuming you want to get the user, bundle, role, and pool, then I would do the following, may be off depending on how your actual DB and models are set up

```
// Relationship.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function bundle()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Bundle::class, 'id', 'related_id');
}
```

```
// Bundle.php
public function relationship()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Relationship::class, 'related_id');
}
```

```
// Role.php
public function relationship()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Relationship::class);
}
```

```
// Pool.php
public function bundle()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Bundle::class);
}
```

Then you could do something like

```
Pool::with('bundle.relationship.user')->whereIn('name', $pools);
Role::with('relationship.user')->whereIn('name', $roles);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I had set up relationships in the following models (that's why I tried writing req #2 and #3)
A role may have many relationships and same with a bundle, it may have multiple relationships.
This being said, what I want:

ideally: a JSON array with user's first name, user's last name, user's email, user's role in bundle, bundle's name and pool's name

else: Pools -> bundle -> relationships -> role, user

Must only appear if bundle.name in $pools and role.name in $roles.
How can I get that using what you wrote and selecting only the fields I want in each table ?

Comment: If the models are set up, and you want these properties attached to a model for a response, then you can define an attribute https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor then add it to the appends property of the model

Comment: The specified attributes are attached in the response, it's all the others that also are that I don't want. In any way, I still can't figure how to make my request with all the datas I need

Comment: To hide a property you can add it to the hidden property of the model or you can create an api resource to define what should and shouldn't show on the response